# Multiple SELECTs in one query using same WITH

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query filters some IDs from a master table, and returns all data abpout that IDs from two other tables as two record sets:

```
WITH filteredIds (fid) AS 
(
    SELECT id 
    FROM MasterTable 
    WHERE <somecondition>
)
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
RIGHT JOIN filteredIds ON (Table1.id = filteredIds.fid);

WITH filteredIds (fid) AS 
(
    SELECT id 
    FROM MasterTable 
    WHERE <somecondition>
)
SELECT * 
FROM Table2 
RIGHT JOIN filteredIds ON (Table2.id = filteredIds.fid);
```

This works so far, but it would be great to have just one WITH clause, since the condition is always the same. Further more, the condition is often written manually, since this is used to collect some diagnostics data.

But this

```
WITH filteredIds (fid) AS 
(
    SELECT id 
    FROM MasterTable 
    WHERE <somecondition>
)
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
RIGHT JOIN filteredIds ON (Table1.id = filteredIds.fid);

SELECT * 
FROM Table2 
RIGHT JOIN filteredIds ON (Table2.id = filteredIds.fid);
```

does not work, SQL Server claims it does not know object `filteredIds` in the last query.

Have I overseen something, or doesn't it work that way? I guess the alternative would be a temporary table.

Comment: A CTE is just a part of another single sql statement. Its definition does not exist outside of the statement where it is defined and populated. In that respect, it is exactly the same as a derived table.

Comment: If the columns are similar enough, perhaps a `union all`? Or what about an inline Table Valued Function, basically a parameterized view? By the way, `right join` is strange, there is nothing you can do with `right` that you can't do with `left`

Answer (score 1):

Once a CTE has been consumed in a query, it cannot be reused in another query.  There is no direct workaround as far as I know.  The closest thing perhaps to want you want would be to create a bona fide temporary table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #temp (fid int);
INSERT INTO #temp (fid)
SELECT id FROM MasterTable WHERE <somecondition>;
```

Then, you may reuse the temporary table directly:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table1 a RIGHT JOIN #temp b ON a.id = b.fid;
SELECT * FROM Table2 a RIGHT JOIN #temp b ON a.id = b.fid;
```

Comment: You overstate things a bit - you can have multiple CTE query definitions but only one WITH clause.

Comment: @SMor Once a CTE has been consumed in a query, it cannot be reused in another query.  Let me change my language.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, to me a `VIEW` seems closer to CTE than a temporary table. At least in SQL Server, because both views and CTEs are not materialized and inlined in the main query and optimized as a single big query.

Comment: @Vlad I agree...I didn't think of views when I wrote my answer (which is still valid by the way).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want with CTE. CTE doesn't exist outside the query where it was defined.

I think that the closest thing to what you want is called a "view".

```
CREATE VIEW filteredIds
AS
SELECT id AS fid
FROM MasterTable 
WHERE <somecondition>
;
```

And now you can use that view in many other queries.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
RIGHT JOIN filteredIds ON (Table1.id = filteredIds.fid);

SELECT * 
FROM Table2 
RIGHT JOIN filteredIds ON (Table2.id = filteredIds.fid);
```

Furthermore, in SQL Server it will work exactly like a CTE in a sense that the list of filtered IDs is not materialized and the engine will optimize the whole query that references the view. It will inline the view definition into the outer / main query as if you wrote everything in one big query. Just like it would do with CTE.

With a temporary table you explicitly write this temporary result to disk and read it back.

In some cases it may be better, in some not.